# Macro to fill out field names, values, and switch statements of a custom @:enum abstract?

Tags: macros, haxe

I have a bit of a unique situation. For various reasons, chiefly interoperating with a nullable [stringly typed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) legacy system, as well as various other needs I won't go into at the moment, I've settled on a custom @:enum abstract that looks like this:

```
@:enum abstract MyEnum(Null<Int>) {

    public var A = 0;
    public var B = 1;
    public var C = 2;
    public var D = 3;
    public var E = 4;
    public var F = 5;
    public var G = 6;

    @:from private static function fromString (value:String):MyEnum {

        return switch (value) {

            case "a": A;
            case "b": B;
            case "c": C;
            case "d": D;
            case "e": E;
            case "f": F;
            case "g": G;
            default: null;

        }

    }

    @:to private static function toString (value:Int):String {

        return switch (value) {

            case A: "a";
            case B: "b";
            case C: "c";
            case D: "d";
            case E: "e";
            case F: "f";
            case G: "g";
            default: null;

        }

    }

}
```

However, that's an annoyingly large amount of things to type, and when adding and removing members it's easy to make a manual error. Clearly, this follows a super predictable pattern and seems like a great thing to construct with a macro, but I am terrible at haxe macros.

Can someone explain how I could use a macro to build this enum in such a way that all I have to supply is a list of field names?

pseudocode:

```
@:enum abstract MyEnum = doTheMacroMagic(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]);
```

The logical steps would be:

- Declare public vars from field names (upper case)
- Declare fromString/toString values from field names (lower case)
- Set public vars to 0-based integers and follow same order as field names are supplied

I think a simple practical example like this might make haxe macros finally "click" for me if I can see it in action.

Comment: I did a macro some time ago for the `toString()` part https://gist.github.com/mrcdk/7bef01fe1c1fb746f17f When working with abstracts you have to keep in mind that any function will be static and will have as its first parameter the base type of the abstract. For example, for an `abstract E(Int) {}` the signature of `toString` will be `static function toString(x:Int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flixel handles a very similar use case in for classes like `FlxKey` with [`FlxMacroUtil.buildMap()`](https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel/blob/90aebe0fdd0c3ec568c6d2a7c3f9c60be9a6c635/flixel/system/macros/FlxMacroUtil.hx#L14). This expression macro looks for all uppercase, inline vars it finds in the abstract and generates a `Map<String, EnumType>` from it, with the keys being the field names and the values the field values (or the inverse of that if `invert` is `true`).

```
@:enum
abstract FlxKey(Int) from Int to Int
{
    public static var fromStringMap(default, null):Map<String, FlxKey>
        = FlxMacroUtil.buildMap("flixel.input.keyboard.FlxKey");

    public static var toStringMap(default, null):Map<FlxKey, String>
        = FlxMacroUtil.buildMap("flixel.input.keyboard.FlxKey", true);

    var A              = 65;
    var B              = 66;
    // more keys...

    @:from
    public static inline function fromString(s:String)
    {
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        return fromStringMap.exists(s) ? fromStringMap.get(s) : NONE;
    }

    @:to
    public inline function toString():String
    {
        return toStringMap.get(this);
    }
}
```

I'd imagine that's a good starting point. If you want to generate the entire `abstract`, you will need a `@:build` macro.

---

Answering the follow-up question, how to generate fields: This is actually quite straightforward with a build macro:

```
@:enum
@:build(Macro.createVariables(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]))
abstract Generated(Int)
{
}
```

`Macro.hx` (sensible to have in its own file to avoid having to deal with `#if macro` conditionals):

```
package;

import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class Macro
{
    public static macro function createVariables(varNames:Array<String>):Array<Field>
    {
        // get the current fields of the calling type (empty array in this case)
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        for (i in 0...varNames.length)
            // create a custom variable and add it to the fields
            fields.push(createVariable(varNames[i], i));
        return fields;
    }

    private static function createVariable(name:String, value:Int):Field
    {
        return {
            name: name,
            doc: null,
            meta: [],
            access: [Access.APublic, Access.AStatic, Access.AInline],
            kind: FieldType.FVar(macro:Int, macro $v{value}),
            pos: Context.currentPos()
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice the fields showing up in auto-completion for `Generated.`. You can also see what's been generated by looking at the `Generated_Impl.dump` when doing an AST dump.

Comment: Probably easier to make the empty abstract yourself and then fill it in with macro, like flixel does. It's possible to make the whole thing yourself, but it's simpler and faster to do it yourself if you already know what it'll be called.

Macros are hardly documented though, I always learn by trial and error :(

Comment: This is a great starting point!

Specifically though -- do you know how to start with this:

```fields == ["A","B","C","D","E"]```

and wind up with this?


    `public var A = 0;`
    `public var B = 1;`
    `public var C = 2;`
    `public var D = 3;`
    `public var E = 4;`

Comment: This is exactly what I need :P